# Cannot set background-image to specific Angular component due to _reboot.scss

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set **background-image** to my specific **Angular component** using code below:

```
body { 
        background-image: url(...); 
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

This piece of code is placed in .css file which belongs to Angular component.

However, in browser console I have noticed that **_reboot.scss** class (which probably comes from Bootstrap) is overwriting my above code snippet to default background-color.

I have already tried almost all of things and the only way to change background-image is to modify _reboot.scss class in browser using F12 mode.

Comment: Did you try `background-image: url(...) !important;`

Comment: give the body a class for example 'bg' and then apply any style you want to it

Comment: Is your concern about the `background-color` or the `backgroud-image`?

Comment: @dileepkumarjami yes, i tried !important and it still doesn't work. My concern is about background-image

Comment: @mostafatourad i have already tried to put the whole component into one div and give it a class which has background-image in it, however it wasn't stretched to the full screen

Comment: Why did you have colon here `body: {` Try `body {`

Comment: @dileepkumarjami true thanks, i have missclicked one of the key during writing this post, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: can you try to add your code snippet in codesandbox to see your problem .

Answer (score 0):

you can set your code to:

```
._reboot.scss { 
        background-image: url(...); 
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

to override Bootstrap.

or, give *!important* to your css :

```
body { 
        background-image: url(...)!important; 
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried adding !important to my code and it doesn't solve my problem.